# Dual-monitor setup on Gnome / Nvidia

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, desktop, nvidia-graphics-card

This issue has been driving me nuts all day... I hope someone can point me in the right direction. Here's the situation overview:

- Nvidia videocard (Dell Dimension 9200)
- Freshly installed Fedora 14
- The proprietary Nvidia drivers have been installed (no Nouveau driver)
- Window Manager is set to Compiz (with wobbly windows and everything)
- going to System -> Preferences -> Monitors tells me I have a single screen composed of the resolution of both screens (so the monitors are already abstracted away).

The problem: the desktop behaves like a giant screen spanning the both monitors. I'd prefer the behaviour as seen on MacOS X and Windows, where both monitors are treated as a separate screen, between which content can be dragged.

The most problematic is maximizing windows: instead of blowing up to fill the currently active monitor, they blow up covering both screens with a giant window.

In my NVIDIA X Server Settings panel I have the following:
- Two screens are recognized.
- The configuration is "TwinView"
- Setting the configuration to "Separate X Windows" results in one monitor being disabled upon restarting X, the other remaining in TwinView mode.

(please note that I have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to X, and would prefer not manually meddle with its configuration files, if it can be avoided).

Any tips?

Comment: I would remove the Nvidia driver to see what happens.

Comment: Not an option; without the NVidia driver the GPU fan blows at 100% constantly, inciting murderous tendencies among my coworkers.